# Calculate and display % change for 2 rows in 3rd row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table to compare Monthly Sales data on the Year-to-Year basis. This table will get updated every month by replacing the records with sales data for last month-same year and the year before.

```
Month_Year || Sale_Vol || #Sales || Average_Price
  Mar-17   ||   1250   ||   25   ||   50
  Mar-18   ||    900   ||   20   ||   45
```

I need to display % change ((Mar-18)/(Mar-17) - 1)*100 in an additional row as shown below

```
Month_Year || Sale_Vol || #Sales || Average_Price
  Mar-17   ||   1250   ||   25   ||   50
  Mar-18   ||    900   ||   15   ||   60
Prcnt_Chng ||    -28   ||  -40   ||   20
```

I am not able to figure out how to achieve this. This is what I have written so far but it's not elegant.

```
SELECT 'Percentage Change',NULL, 
100.0 * ((select * from Tbl where [Month_Year] = left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)),112),6))-(select * from Tbl where [Month_Year] = left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-12,0)),112),6)))/(select * from Tbl where [Month_Year] = left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)),112),6));
```

And also, I get the error:

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Comment: Is the real question to display the change each day, or is there literally just two rows

Comment: It will change every month

Comment: ok, so compare changes per month across N years

Comment: Not across N years. Just last Month-same year and a year before. I have edited the question but not sure if it is clearer.

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: Just edited the question to add the code I have written so far. I know it's not right and it's not working either.

Comment: Does your table consist of two rows only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, reason of your error is, counts are mismatched. i.e 100 is single substance, which is out of subquery. But in-side of subuquery, you return more than one column. if you correct that, you'll you get table(may be or not which will your resulting table)
I trying to query for you..!

Edited:

```
   select * from yourtable  -- get previous table
   union
   select 'Prcnt_Chng ',(  -- to get calculated row
   ((((select Sale_Vol from yourtable where Month_Year = 'Mar-18')/  --value of Sale_Vol of mar 18
   (select Sale_Vol from yourtable where Month_Year = 'Mar-17'))-1)  --value of Sale_Vol of mar 18. divided and sub by 1 
   100),                                                              -- mul by 100
   ((((select [#Sales] from yourtable where Month_Year = 'Mar-18')/  --value of [#Sales] of mar 18
   (select [#Sales] from yourtable where Month_Year = 'Mar-17'))-1)  --value of [#Sales] of mar 18. divided and sub by 1
   100),                                                              -- mul by 100
   ((((select Average_Price from yourtable where Month_Year = 'Mar-18')/  --value of Average_Price of mar 18
   (select Average_Price from yourtable where Month_Year = 'Mar-17'))-1)  --value of Average_Price of mar 18. divided and sub by 1
   100))                                                                   -- mul by 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have only two rows in your table, you could try this query

```
;with cte as (
    select
        *, rn = row_number() over (order by Month_Year)
    from
        myTable
)

select * from myTable
union all
select
    'Prcnt_Chng', 100 * b.Sale_Vol / a.Sale_Vol - 100
    , 100 * b.[#Sales] / a.[#Sales] - 100
    , 100 * b.Average_Price / a.Average_Price - 100
from
    cte a
    join cte b on a.rn + 1 = b.rn
where a.rn = 1
```